# Printing the minimum and costomizing the outputs

Tags: python, arrays, printing, minimum

In the following code I print out entire outputs and the minimum of them:

```
l=  4.98648387414 q=  4.96850590047
l=  6.22734941766 8.30807062837 q=  2.50807065862 6.36351958551
l=  6.55113742501 8.91180674608 1.62449083617 q=  6.58695963821 0.0460316539106 6.79113942876
min is= [ 6.55113743  8.91180675  1.62449084] [ 6.58695964  0.04603165  6.79113943]
```

But the output that I want to have is the minimum of `l` and the relevant `q` which means:

`min is= [1.62449084] [6.79113943]`

How should I do that and another question is that How should print out the outputs in a column not in front of each other.
like this:

```
l=  4.98648387414 q=  4.96850590047   #for i=1
l=  6.22734941766 q=  2.50807065862   #for i=2
l=  8.30807062837 q=  6.36351958551   #for i=2
```

the code is:

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
a=None
temp=1e10
for i in range (1,4):
    r=np.random.uniform(0,3,i)
    x=np.random.uniform(0,9,i)    
    h=np.random.uniform(0,1,i)
    l=h*10
    if (l<1.0).any():
        q=r
    elif (l>1.0).any():
        q=x
    print("l= ",*l, "q= ",*q)

    if (l<temp).any():
        temp=l
        a=q
print("min is=", temp,a)
```

I appreciate your help and your consideration.

Comment: Do you need a loop where you generate first 1 random value, then 2, then 3, or could you generate all 6 values in a row ? Because at the end, it seems that you only need the min for the 6 values, no matter the step during which it has been generated. If that's the case, the algorithm could be implement much more efficiently.

Comment: @sciroccorics I need the whole number of `l` in a column and relevant `q` in another column. In addition I need to find minimum of `I` and its `q`

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you need to print all six (l,q) couples and find the min for all of them, there is no difference to generate 6 values in one shot, instead of 1+2+3. So try this code, and let me know if it solves the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random

r = np.random.uniform(0,3,6)
x = np.random.uniform(0,9,6)
h = np.random.uniform(0,10,6) # no need for l = 10*h
q = np.where(h < 1.0, r, x)

for xh, xq in zip(h, q):
    print("h = %.7f    q = %.7f" % (xh, xq))
index = np.argmin(h)
print("min is:\nh = %.7f    q = %.7f" % (h[index], q[index]))
```

The key is in function `np.where` that allows one to select items from two different arrays (here, h or q) according to the items of a third array (here h), which is exactly what you need here.

Comment: thank you. `l` was our function, I simplified it. on the other hand, we do need both those if statements.  my code is correct before the line containing `q=x`

Comment: we can use
`output = '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,row)) for row in zip(l,q))` to have them in columns with `print(output)`, but finding the minimum is our challenge then.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the difference between generating 6 sets of random numbers, and generating 1 set, then 2, then 3. If you need some data structure to organize your data, you should explain a bit more. It's hard to help if we don't have the whole constraints.

Comment: if we delete the whole code after `q=x` and the add
output = '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,row)) for row in zip(l,q))
print(output)
we get the proper out put. but finding the minimum value is the problem. finding the min value of `l` and its relevant which is `q`. q is not minimum just is in the row of min`l`.

Comment: I guess your code before `q=x` is not correct. You are performing a loop on `i` but in the second loop step, you discard all work done in step 1, and in step 3, you discard all work done in step 2. When you compute `output` you simply use data from step 3, so step 1 and step 2 are totally useless. So why use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as f:
for x in zip(l,q):
            f.write("{0}\t{1}\n".format(x[0],x[1])) #Writing the whole numbers in a txt file
print(min(l) #finding the minimum of l
```

in other file you can use this code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('output.txt', header=None, sep='\s+')
findingtherelevant = df[df[0] == "min(l)"].values[0]
prin(findingtherelevant)
```